# Error updating MariaDB (to 10.1.42) in CentOS and Ubunto

Tags: centos, centos7, yum, mariadb

Yum is failing to update MariaDB to version 10.1.42.
`yum check-update` presents available updates for MariaDB (server, client, common, etc.) and galera.

```
MariaDB-client.x86_64                                    10.1.42-1.el7.centos                                    mariadb
MariaDB-common.x86_64                                    10.1.42-1.el7.centos                                    mariadb
MariaDB-devel.x86_64                                     10.1.42-1.el7.centos                                    mariadb
(...)
```

However, `yum update` fails to update these packages.

```
MariaDB-common-10.1.42-1.el7.c FAILED                                          
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-common-10.1.42-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
MariaDB-devel-10.1.42-1.el7.ce FAILED                                          
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64/rpms/MariaDB-devel-10.1.42-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
(...)
Error downloading packages:
  MariaDB-server-10.1.42-1.el7.centos.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  MariaDB-shared-10.1.42-1.el7.centos.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  MariaDB-client-10.1.42-1.el7.centos.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Packages for version 10.1.42 were removed. Install 10.1.43 instead

The error is `HTTP Error 404` which means those files are not present in the repository.
I checked the repository for CentOS 7 and I found packages for versions 10.1.40, 10.1.41, and 10.1.43, **but not for version 10.1.42**.

Version 10.1.42 has a bug that prevents the MariaDB server from starting (see [MDEV-20987](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20987)).
Consequently, affected packages has been removed from MariaDB repositories.

Try to update to the most recent version using:

```sh
yum clean expire-cache # next time, `yum update` will find the most recent version
yum update mariadb-* galera
```